# ofuscar codigo javascript com php

Tags: php, javascript, lógica

Estou com uma duvida em relação a um ofuscador de codigo javascript feito em php.. [https://damidev.000webhostapp.com](https://damidev.000webhostapp.com/)

alguem pode me ajudar a entender como esse cara fez pra gerar ?

Answer (score 0):

Hoje a maioria dos projetos com desenvolvimento sério em javascript acabando fazendo isso com o nodejs e webpack como parte do processo de *build*.

Com PHP, pesquisando rápido encontrei esse library, o [PHP-Packer](https://github.com/tholu/php-packer).

Basicamente com ele você passa o código javascript e ele te retorna o código ofuscado.

```php
 $js = file_get_contents('test.js');
 $packer = new Tholu\Packer\Packer($js, 'Normal', true, false, true);
 $packed_js = $packer->pack();
 echo $packed_js;
```

Comment: então eu quero implementar isso porque um site meu esta sofrendo com crawlers, estão acessando o meu site e roubando informações pelo html..
com esse método packer (packed) é facil reconhecer um padrão e capturar oque quiser: https://pastebin.com/BZEsmxNm.. porem com o método desse site https://damidev.000webhostapp.com deixa tudo escondido: https://pastebin.com/tw90KYSi, assim dificultando a vida desses crawlers entendeu ? pois se você reparar ele sempre gera um código diferente mesmo com a mesma entrada de js .. tava estudando e percebi que é um método em XOR ou algo assim..

Comment: Entendi. Se o crawler que estiver roubando seu conteúdo tiver a condição de executar javascript, não importar qual dos dois você vai usar, pois para esse código renderizar, ele vai ter que virar HTML. De qualquer forma, vale a pena você editar a pergunta e colocar essa essa informação extra.

Comment: talvez um captcha seja uma melhor solução.

Comment: captcha não é solução pois os dados são de paginas e dados de video coisas do tipo eu realmente preciso disso, sobre o crawler ele é pelo que sei so abstrai partes especificas não sei se renderiza mais mesmo assim ofuscar ajuda muito